# Issue with multiple entries on webpack using name "Main"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am very new to using react, node js, and express. To get started I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-nodejs-with-react-and-jsx?view=vs-2022) tutorial from the official docs.

From my understanding, I have my webpack-config.js setup with multiple entries with the intent to generate multiple js files.

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: "development",
    entry:
    {
        app: "./src/app/app.tsx",
        test: "./src/test/test.tsx"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: './[name]-app-bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'ts-loader'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, when I run `npm run build` or `node_modules\.bin\webpack ./src/app/app.tsx ./src/test/test.tsx --config webpack-config.js` I get the output:

```
> webpack-cli ./src/app/app.tsx ./src/test/test.tsx --config webpack-config.js

asset ./main-app-bundle.js 1.09 MiB [compared for emit] (name: main) 1 related asset
runtime modules 123 bytes 1 module
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.08 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 85.7 KiB
    ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js 85.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 1000 KiB
    ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js 1000 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 17.3 KiB
    ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js 198 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js 17.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/ 2.9 KiB
  ./src/app/app.tsx 2.65 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./src/test/test.tsx 250 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 1687 ms
```

From what I can see, both of my entries are being named "Main" as the file generated is named "main-app-bundle.js" and this is only generating the one js file (plus the map). After hours of researching and trying fixes, I am still unsure where I am going wrong here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The whole point of webpack is to bundle multiple modules into a single file? The message says "compiled successfully"? Have you tried running a server using the `dist` folder as root?

Comment: @ChrisG I am able to get the sever running. I link the generated script file to the html file and the logic seems to work fine unless you get an element that does not exist. Maybe this is more a misunderstanding on my part. I was under the impression that if I wanted to add a new page to my website I would need to use a new .tsx (and generated .js) file for that page. Am I supposed to be using a single .tsx file for multiple pages?

Comment: That completely depends on how your app is going to work. React apps don't use classical navigation where you click links that lead to a new document being loaded. You can simulate this behavior using react-router but a React app is almost always a one page app. You can absolutely use a dedicated .tsx file for each page but you don't have to.

Comment: When you create a React app with a node/express backend, express usually does two things: 1) serve the static files that make up the React app 2) provide an API for the app to load/process data.

Comment: Here's a very basic example showing how navigation might look like: https://jsfiddle.net/3Le0stfk/

Comment: @ChrisG Ohh that makes much more sense. I'm coming from ruby on rails and I wanted to make a small portfolio website but, don't need everything that rails offers. I was thinking along the lines of using express routing to serve static pages built with react similar to how rails might work but, it's obvious that I need to research more into react conventions. It seems to act more as a state machine. Thank you! Now I can stop chasing after creating multiple bundles.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#separate-app-and-vendor-entries

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the environment that you have in your webpack and if it works for me, just run "npx webpack build" because I don't know what script you run with BUILD; in my environment, it works I'll share the files for you to see.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/app.js",
    test: "./src/test.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "./[name]-app-bundle.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".Webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "ts-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "letcode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "example.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#separate-app-and-vendor-entries